# Angular: material table to restart index count for lists in table cell

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6, mat-table

I have a mat-table with multiple columns and rows where for one of the columns, each cell contains a list of strings. I have the list items being numbered by using index but the count just keeps incrementing in each subsequent row. For example

1. stuff
2. more stuff
3. even more stuff

   ---
4. things
5. other things

with 1, 2 and 3 being in row 1 and 4 and 5 being in row 2

What I want is the count/index to start over in each row, so like this

1. stuff
2. more stuff
3. even more stuff

   ---
4. things
5. other things

```
<ng-container matColumnDef='start'>
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Start</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef='let row; let i = index;'>{{i+1}}:{{row.start}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

**I want** each row's list in that particular cell/column to start the count over from 1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From your question:

- `mat-table` with multiple columns and rows
- for one of the columns, each cell contains a list of strings.
- For the list items being numbered by using index but the count just keeps incrementing in each subsequent row
- You **wanted** the count to restart from 1 for each particular cell/column

relevant **HTML**:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
  The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <ng-container matColumnDef="index">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let j = index"> {{j+1}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Position </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let j = index"> 
      <p *ngFor='let item of element.position;let i =index'>
        {{i+1}} - {{item}}
      </p>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

relevant **TS**:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: string[];
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: ['stuff 1', 'some stuff', 'some more stuff'] , name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: ['things 2', 'some things', 'some more things'], name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: ['items 3', 'some items'], name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: ['stuff 4', 'some stuff' ], name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: ['stuff 5', 'some stuff', 'some more stuff'], name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: ['stuff 6', 'some stuff', 'some more stuff'], name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: ['stuff 7', 'some stuff', 'some more stuff'], name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: ['stuff 8', 'some stuff', 'some more stuff'], name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: ['stuff 9', 'some stuff', 'some more stuff'], name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: ['stuff 10', 'some stuff', 'some more stuff'], name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['index', 'position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pybj6c)